# how to user expect and send with a request and sleep

Tags: shell, expect

When the password appeare
I want to use expect to autoinput the result of a request after 5s

macOS shell expect

```
expect << !
set timeout -1
spawn bundle exec fastlane fastlane-credentials add --username sakura
expect "*Password*"
sleep 5
send `curl http://localhost/a.txt`

interact
!
```

the sleep can't effect
the `curl http://localhost/a.txt` used before the Password，I want to after

Comment: Don't use backticks: the shell is hijacking those and performing the curl before expect launches. Use plain quotes: `send "curl http://localhost/a.txt"`

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: but if I use the " its just a string , I want to a result of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tcl language, send command interpret at every first time, so the sleep will not work for interact with your process. Put sleep before expect should work, but U need save password in temp file as a storage. More detail, example codes show as:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1
spawn bundle exec fastlane fastlane-credentials add --username sakura
sleep 5
send_user "[exec curl -s http://localhost/a.txt -o /tmp/_passwd.txt]" 
set fp [open "/tmp/_passwd.txt" r]
set passwd [read $fp]
close $fp
send_user "[exec rm -f /tmp/tmp/_passwd.txt]"
puts $passwd
expect "*Password*"
send '$passwd\r'
interact
```